# Get list of recommended packages (suggestions) for touch screen support after apt-get install lxde

Tags: software-recommendation, apt, dpkg, aptitude, touchscreen

I was manually installing X server and lxde on my cellphone's chrooted ubuntu.

There were a couple of packages suggested after install related to touchscreen support.

I can't remember the name of those packages. I checked the apt and dpkg logs and history but it only shows the messages during install not the suggestions after.

How can I get again this suggestions without reinstalling?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `$ apt-cache show lxde | grep Suggests` ?

Comment: nope, I guess these suggestions came from a required automatically selected package (there where at least 20 and I would like not having to check them all), but still, great command you just introduced me to, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just found this today, for anyone who will be referring this in the future,

```
$ apt-cache depends lxde
```

If you want just the recommends, you can grep it.

```
$ apt-cache depends lxde |grep -i recommends
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the packages dependencies and only the ones that are related to touchscreens you might use nested commands:

```
apt-cache depends lxde
```

Here we get all dependencies. Now lets get the name of the packages only:

```
apt-cache depends lxde | awk -F': ' '{print $2}'
```

Now, getting rid of undesirable symbols `<` and `>`:

```
apt-cache depends lxde | awk -F': ' '{print $2}' | sed 's|[<>,]||g'
```

Now lets wrap it all in an apt-show:

```
apt-cache show $(apt-cache depends lxde | awk -F': ' '{print $2}' | sed 's|[<>,]||g') | grep -i touch
```

You will notice at the end a `grep -i touch`, you can change the touch part for whatever you are looking.